# How to escape in HTML5 data-attribute

Tags: json, html, custom-data-attribute

The data-attribute stuff is new to me and just realized I need to escape space, comma, etc. Can anyone give me some suggestions on my approach? Below is my code:

```
#A list holds all the strings to be sent to data-attribute, 
#the sequence and length of the list is dynamic, determined by the user 
#(That's why I need to find a way to escape automatically.

Apt_p = []
Apt_p.append('Relative to planting')
Apt_p.append('Relative to harvest')
Apt_p_j=json.dumps(Apt_p) #convert everything into JSON for future usage

#I think below is the place to let escape happen.
html = """<td id="Apt_p_j" data-val=%s></td>""" %(Apt_p_j)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your attribute value inside double quotes so you don't need to worry about escaping spaces.  Then escape it just like you would escape any other attribute in quotes.  Your web framework should have a function for that.

Comment: I added double quotes to the data-attribute(data-val="%s"), but now the return is '['. But then I added single quote(data-val='%s'). It works! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if fire bug lets you see the actual source or just current state of the DOM.  It's not that double quotes don't work: in general they work fine, but you are obviously forgetting to escape the double quotes in your json string.